# I have written this stored procedure in oracle 9i its not correct and i need the correct syntax

Tags: oracle

here i created a stored procedure but its not working
here are something that is wrong with the syntax can anyone help

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MISSALESVSCOLLECTION

    ( 
        FROMDATE  IN  DATE, 
        TODATE IN DATE 
    ) 
AS 
BEGIN 
SELECT SUM(TBLORDERSTYLE.NQTY * TBLORDERSTYLE.NUNITPRICE/ 1000) AS TOTAL, TBLORDER.NPAYMODE, 
(SELECT SUM(NEXPAMOUNT) FROM TBLEXPLC WHERE DINVDATE BETWEEN  TO_DATE(FROMDATE) AND TO_DATE(TODATE) 
AND  (CEXPLCNO LIKE '%TT%'  OR CEXPLCNO LIKE '%SC%') 
) AS TT, 
(SELECT SUM(NEXPAMOUNT) FROM TBLEXPLC WHERE DINVDATE BETWEEN  TO_DATE(FROMDATE) AND TO_DATE(TODATE) 
AND  (CEXPLCNO NOT LIKE '%TT%'  OR CEXPLCNO NOT LIKE '%SC%' OR CEXPLCNO NOT LIKE '%MR#%') 
) AS LC, 
(SELECT SUM(TBLORDERSTYLE.NQTY * TBLORDERSTYLE.NUNITPRICE/ 1000) FROM TBLORDER 
INNER JOIN  
TBLORDERSTYLE   
ON 
TBLORDER.CORDERNO = TBLORDERSTYLE.CORDERNO  
WHERE TBLORDER.NPAYMODE = '3'  
AND  TBLORDER.CLCNO  LIKE '%MR#%'  
AND TBLORDER.DPICONFIRMDATE BETWEEN  TO_DATE(FROMDATE) AND TO_DATE(TODATE) 
)AS CASH 
FROM TBLORDER 
INNER JOIN  
TBLORDERSTYLE   
ON 
TBLORDER.CORDERNO = TBLORDERSTYLE.CORDERNO AND 
     TBLORDER.NPOSTFLAG = '1' AND  
    TBLORDER.DPICONFIRMDATE BETWEEN   TO_DATE(FROMDATE) AND TO_DATE(TODATE) 
GROUP BY TBLORDER.NPAYMODE 
END;
```

Comment: Try running it. If wrong, Oracle will print an `ORA-#####` error code together with a description of the error and, possibly, a line number to help identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you cant just select a result set in PL/SQL. you have to do something with it. when you have multiple rows you need to enclose that select with a `for a in (your sql)`. i.e. in your case:

```
create or replace procedure missalesvscollection(fromdate in date, todate in date) 
as
begin
  for r_row in (select sum(tblorderstyle.nqty * tblorderstyle.nunitprice / 1000) as total,
         tblorder.npaymode,
         (select sum(nexpamount)
             from tblexplc
            where dinvdate between to_date(fromdate) and to_date(todate)
              and (cexplcno like '%TT%' or cexplcno like '%SC%')) as tt,
         (select sum(nexpamount)
             from tblexplc
            where dinvdate between to_date(fromdate) and to_date(todate)
              and (cexplcno not like '%TT%' or cexplcno not like '%SC%' or
                  cexplcno not like '%MR#%')) as lc,
         (select sum(tblorderstyle.nqty * tblorderstyle.nunitprice / 1000)
             from tblorder
            inner join tblorderstyle
               on tblorder.corderno = tblorderstyle.corderno
            where tblorder.npaymode = '3'
              and tblorder.clcno like '%MR#%'
              and tblorder.dpiconfirmdate between to_date(fromdate) and to_date(todate)) as cash
    from tblorder
   inner join tblorderstyle
      on tblorder.corderno = tblorderstyle.corderno
     and tblorder.npostflag = '1'
     and tblorder.dpiconfirmdate between to_date(fromdate) and to_date(todate)
   group by tblorder.npaymode)
   loop
     -- do something here.
   end loop;
end;
```

within that loop, you'd do processing as you want. if you just want to print the columns out you can use `DBMS_OUTPUT` like:

```
dbms_output.put_line('total = ' || r_row.total);
dbms_output.put_line('npaymode= ' || r_row.npaymode);
```

etc.

if your idea is that you just want to return that result set to the caller, you can return a ref cursor instead.

ie something like :

```
create or replace function missalesvscollection(fromdate in date, todate in date) 
return sys_refcursor
as
  v_rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  open v_rc
  for
  select sum(tblorderstyle.nqty * tblorderstyle.nunitprice / 1000) as total,
         tblorder.npaymode,
         (select sum(nexpamount)
             from tblexplc
            where dinvdate between to_date(fromdate) and to_date(todate)
              and (cexplcno like '%TT%' or cexplcno like '%SC%')) as tt,
         (select sum(nexpamount)
             from tblexplc
            where dinvdate between to_date(fromdate) and to_date(todate)
              and (cexplcno not like '%TT%' or cexplcno not like '%SC%' or
                  cexplcno not like '%MR#%')) as lc,
         (select sum(tblorderstyle.nqty * tblorderstyle.nunitprice / 1000)
             from tblorder
            inner join tblorderstyle
               on tblorder.corderno = tblorderstyle.corderno
            where tblorder.npaymode = '3'
              and tblorder.clcno like '%MR#%'
              and tblorder.dpiconfirmdate between to_date(fromdate) and to_date(todate)) as cash
    from tblorder
   inner join tblorderstyle

      on tblorder.corderno = tblorderstyle.corderno
     and tblorder.npostflag = '1'
     and tblorder.dpiconfirmdate between to_date(fromdate) and to_date(todate)
   group by tblorder.npaymode;

  return v_rc;

end;
```